# Flink: ProcessWindowFunction

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am recently studying `ProcessWindowFunction` in Flink's new release. It says the `ProcessWindowFunction` supports global state and window state. I use Scala API to give it a try. I can so far get the global state working but I do no have any luck to make it for the window state. What I'm doing is to process system logs and count the number of logs keyed by hostname and severity level. I would like to calculate the difference in log count between two adjacent windows. Here is my code implementing `ProcessWindowFunction`.

```
class LogProcWindowFunction extends ProcessWindowFunction[LogEvent, LogEvent, Tuple, TimeWindow] {
  // Create a descriptor for ValueState
  private final val valueStateWindowDesc = new ValueStateDescriptor[Long](
    "windowCounters",
    createTypeInformation[Long])

  private final val reducingStateGlobalDesc = new ReducingStateDescriptor[Long](
    "globalCounters",
    new SumReduceFunction(),
    createTypeInformation[Long])

  override def process(key: Tuple, context: Context, elements: Iterable[LogEvent], out: Collector[LogEvent]): Unit = {
    // Initialize the per-key and per-window ValueState
    val valueWindowState = context.windowState.getState(valueStateWindowDesc)
    val reducingGlobalState = context.globalState.getReducingState(reducingStateGlobalDesc)
    val latestWindowCount = valueWindowState.value()
    println(s"lastWindowCount: $latestWindowCount ......")
    val latestGlobalCount = if (reducingGlobalState.get() == null) 0L else reducingGlobalState.get()
    // Compute the necessary statistics and determine if we should launch an alarm
    val eventCount = elements.size
    // Update the related state
    valueWindowState.update(eventCount.toLong)
    reducingGlobalState.add(eventCount.toLong)
    for (elem <- elements) {
      out.collect(elem)
    }
  }
}
```

I always get `0` value from the window state instead of the previous updated count it should be. I've been struggling with such problem for several days. Can someone please help me to figure it out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of the per-window state is a single window instance. In the case of your `process` method above, every time it is called a new window is in scope, and so the latestWindowCount is always zero.

For a normal, vanilla window that is only going to fire once, per-window state is useless. Only if a window somehow has multiple firings (e.g., late firings) can you make good use of the per-window state. If you are trying to remember something from one window to the next, then you can do this with the global window state.

For an example of using per-window state to remember data to use in late firings, see slides 13-19 in Flink's [advanced window training](http://training.data-artisans.com/dataStream/advanced-windowing.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, the code I posted was imitated from the URL you gave. What I thought is that we can initiate per-window states, do some calculation with those states, and then finally to update them so that we can retrieve them within the next window. Therefore, I would expect to get the value of window state retained in the latest call to `ProcessWindowFunction`. I am confused why you would expect the `latestWindowCount` to be zero even if I update the corresponding window state when `ProcessWindowFunction` is called. Am I misunderstanding the usage of per-window state??

Comment: I've expanded my answer to hopefully be more clear. Let me know if you still have questions. Basically it boils down to the fact that the "next window" is not the same window, and does not have access to the per-window state of the previous window.

Comment: Thanks for your update to the answer. Indeed, I misunderstood the definition of per-window state. Now I can completely figure it out.